# Use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to create JSON object including Non-Public/Friend Properties

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, javascriptserializer

Simplified class model:

```
Class ShoppingBasket
    Property Items as BasketItems()
    .....
    Class BasketItems
        Property ItemName as string
        Property ItemPrice as Decimal
        Friend ItemCost as Decimal
        ....
    End Class
```

This is obviously a shopping cart system.

I want to be able to save a serialised string of this shopping basket into a database, simple code:

```
Dim basket as new ShoppingBasket
Dim BasketString as string
Dim JS as new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

BasketString = JS.Serialize(basket).ToString()

.... now save BasketString into the database...
```

This code all runs fine, but I lose the `Friend` declared Property "ItemCost".

This class is used as the return property from an AJAX "Add to Cart" button, so I want the ItemCost property (and various others) to be hidden from the *external* Javascript Console/Development Console in a User's Browser, but need to be able to *internally* save and recover the full class data using the method above.

So, how do I create a `Friend` property so that it can be Serialized when specifically serialized to a string by the JavaScriptSerilaizer class, but not, when it is returned (and internally serialized) by an AJAX `POST` response?

Answer (score 0):

As with `XmlSerializer`, `JavaScriptSerializer` only serializes public properties and fields.  There is no attribute like [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.order.aspx) to force a non-public property to be serialized by `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Instead, you can create a [`JavaScriptConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) of `Friend` scope that serializes and deserializes all the public properties of `BasketItems` automatically, and adds the `ItemCost` also:

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class ShoppingBasket
    Public Property Items as BasketItems()

    Public Class BasketItems
        Public Property ItemName as string
        Public Property ItemPrice as Decimal
        Friend ItemCost as Decimal
    End Class

    Friend Class BasketItemsConverter
        Inherits JavaScriptConverter
        Const ItemCostName As String = "ItemCost"

        Public Overrides Function Deserialize(dictionary As IDictionary(Of String, Object), type As Type, serializer As JavaScriptSerializer) As Object
            ' Perform a default deserialization for public properties.
            Dim myObj = New JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType(Of BasketItems)(dictionary)
            Dim itemCost As Object
            If dictionary.TryGetValue(ItemCostName, itemCost) AndAlso itemCost IsNot Nothing Then
                myObj.ItemCost = serializer.ConvertToType(Of Decimal)(itemCost)
            End If
            Return myObj
        End Function

        Public Overrides Function Serialize(obj As Object, serializer As JavaScriptSerializer) As IDictionary(Of String, Object)
            ' Generate a default serialization for public properties.  Is there an easier way to do this?
            Dim defaultSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim dict = defaultSerializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(defaultSerializer.Serialize(obj))

            Dim basketItem = DirectCast(obj, BasketItems)
            dict(ItemCostName) = basketItem.ItemCost

            Return dict
        End Function

        Public Overrides ReadOnly Property SupportedTypes() As IEnumerable(Of Type)
            Get
                Return { GetType(BasketItems) }
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class       
End Class
```

And then use it like:

```
Dim JS as new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
JS.RegisterConverters({ new ShoppingBasket.BasketItemsConverter() })                

Dim BasketString = JS.Serialize(basket).ToString()
```

Alternatively, you could consider switching to [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) when serializing internally to a string, then marking your non-public properties with [`<JsonProperty>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).